# Optimal Control Problem with Bang-Bang Solution

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics, optimal-control

I am reading Acemoglu, Robinson, Verdier 2017 jpe and stuck at the derivation of the optimal control problem in section IV.D.

The current-value Hamiltonian of the problem is $$H(m(t), u(t), \mu(t))=\omega(u(t)) m(t)^{(1-\theta) / \phi}+\mu(t) \phi\left[g(u(t))-g_{c} m(t)\right]$$, where  $\mu(t)$ is the current-value costate variable and $u(t) \in [0,1]$ is the control variable and $m(t)$ is the state variable. And $\omega\left(u(t)\right)=\omega_{o}\left[1-u(t)\right]+\omega_{c} u(t)$ , and $g\left(u(t)\right)=g_{o}\left[1-u(t)\right]+g_{c} u(t)$.

The maximum principle yields the candidate bang-bang solution: $$u(t)\left\{\begin{array}{lll}=1 & \text { if } \quad \Psi(t)<0 \\ \in[0,1] & \text { if } \quad \Psi(t)=0 \\ =0 & \text { if } \quad \Psi(t)>0\end{array}\right.$$  where $\Psi(t) \equiv\left(\omega_{o}-\omega_{c}\right) m(t)^{(1-\theta) / \phi}-\mu(t) \phi\left[g_{c}-g_{o}\right]$.

And the laws of motion of state variable and costate variable are $$\begin{aligned}
&\dot{m}(t)=\phi\left[g(u(t))-g_{c} m(t)\right] \quad \text { with } m(0)>0 \text { given, } \\
&\dot{\mu}(t)=\left[\rho-(1-\theta) g_{c}+\phi g_{c}\right] \mu(t)-\frac{1-\theta}{\phi} m(t)^{[(1-\theta) / \phi]-1} \omega(u(t))
\end{aligned}$$.

They argue the dynamical system can be analyzed using phase diagrams and define and use $\kappa(t) \equiv \mu(t) m(t)^{(\theta-1) / \phi}$, which transform the choice be $$u(\kappa) \begin{cases}=1 & \text { if } \quad \kappa>\tilde{\kappa} \\ \in[0,1] & \text { if } \quad \kappa=\tilde{\kappa} \\ =0 & \text { if } \quad \kappa<\tilde{\kappa}\end{cases}$$ where  $\tilde{\kappa} \equiv \frac{\omega_{o}-\omega_{c}}{\phi\left(g_{c}-g_{o}\right)}$.

Then they say that the locus for $\dot{\kappa}(t)=0$ is downward sloping (i.e. $\kappa(t)$ decreasing in $m(t)$) and intersects $\tilde{\kappa}$ at $m(t)=\tilde{m}$, and $\tilde{m} \equiv \frac{(1-\theta) g_{o}}{\rho+\phi g_{c}}\left[\frac{\left(g_{c}-g_{o}\right) / g_{o}}{\left(\omega_{o}-\omega_{c}\right) / \omega_{o}}+1\right]$.

I try to use the laws of motion to derive this but the problem I face is that there is the control variable $u(t)$ in these two equations and I don't know how to deal with it.